# Add Maven repository to build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, achartengine

I added a custom maven repository to build.gradle in Android Studio but the dependency is not being found

Maven repository and dependency

```
<repository>
    <id>achartengine</id>
    <name>Public AChartEngine repository</name>
    <url>https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.achartengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>achartengine</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile group: 'org.achartengine', name: 'achartengine', version: '1.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Error message in Android Studio:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My-MobileAndroid'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
  > Could not find org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0.
    Required by:
        :My-MobileAndroid:unspecified
```

What am I missing in build.gradle?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You will need to define the repository outside of `buildscript`. The `buildscript` configuration block only sets up the repositories and dependencies for the classpath of your build script but not your application.

Comment: this sorted the dependency, but Android Studio did not reload the repositories so "import org.achartengine.chart.*;" failed, do you know how to "refresh" the repositories?

Comment: Veryyyy important to follow. Wasted 15 minutes on this one

Comment: should both inside and outside of `buildscript` `repositories` have the same remote repositories?

Answer (score 175):

After

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

You should add this:

```
      repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
            }
        }
```

@Benjamin explained the reason.

If you have a maven with authentication you can use:

```
    repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
               credentials {
                   username xxx
                   password xxx
               }
               url    'http://mymaven/xxxx/repositories/releases/'
            }
    }
```

It is important the order.

Comment: How do we add cloudbees authentication in the gradle file?

Comment: How can I modify Android Studio so that the maven repository is added to build.gradle by default. I keep forgetting about this and have to rediscover why libraries are not loading.

Answer (score 40):

Android Studio Users:

If you want to use grade, go to http://search.maven.org/ and search for your maven repo. Then, click on the "latest version" and in the details page on the bottom left you will see "Gradle" where you can then copy/paste that link into your app's build.gradle.

[image]

Comment: You made my day, thank you very much.
Also, why this isn't in the official ZXing gh page? It shouldn't be so hard to find...

Answer (score 11):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
    // OR another notation:
    // maven {
    //     url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
    // }
}
```

You can also centralize your repository declaration for all your subprojects in *settings.gradle[.kts]* file in newer versions of Gradle (Gradle 7.4):

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

See [the full guide here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) in Gradle documentation website.

Comment: I didn't know the settings.gradle location. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add `repositories` to your build file. For maven repositories you have to prefix repository name with `maven{}`

```
repositories {
  maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
  maven { url "http://maven.restlet.org" }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the maven repository outside the `buildscript` configuration block of your main `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }
```

Make sure that you add them after the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```