# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my first attempt at Android Studio.  I installed 0.8.0 and updated to 0.8.2.  As soon as a project is created I get the error message:

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

C:\Users\Bob\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloAgain6\app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bob.helloagain6"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and C:\Users\Bob\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloAgain6\build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this problem, but suddenly I see the top level `build.gradle` was deleted :), so I copy it from `git` repository and every things goes right

Comment: Same thing for me, my build.gradle for project level was moved into the same folder as the wrapper properties during a funky merge so it wasn't finding it at the root where it should be

Comment: for #FLUTTER projects the solution was to run `./gradlew wrapper` in the `android` directory

Answer (score 494):

## Updated Answer (Dec. 2, 2020)

**Latest Gradle:** [6.5](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Version check:

- `./gradlew -v`

How to update:

- Set URL: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.5 --distribution-type=all`
- Update: `./gradlew wrapper`

**Latest Android Gradle Plugin:** 4.1.0

If you add the following code snippet *to the top* of your `build.gradle` file. Gradle will update the build tools.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // For Gradle 4.0+
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // For Gradle < 4.0
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html and about version compatibility here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle and https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html.

## Original Answer

I had this same error, you need to make sure your **Gradle version is compatible with your Android Gradle Plugin.**

The latest version of Gradle is **2.0** but you need to use **1.12** in order to use the Android Gradle Plugin.

Comment: +1 for still updating your answer a few months later

Comment: @P1nGu1n No problem! It is easier if every sees the most up-to-date information.

Comment: Could you please explain what that code snippet ist for?

Comment: @strom Explain what code snippet? This question was simply upgrading the android gradle dependency.

Comment: Like that. Being a complete  Android/Gradle newbie I was confused by the code you posted. There was no explanation as to where I'm supposed to use it or what it does.

Comment: You should always start with the Android docs, such as the link I provided.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: Thanks a lot! This solution is working very well. I just get confused by adding these lines on top...

Comment: @MartinPfeffer No problem. I will continue to keep this updated!

Comment: Good answer, though I can't help but wonder why Google would deploy Android Studio like this.. This error is the first thing you see when starting a new project. I mean, what were they thinking!?

Comment: @BdR Very good question. I think Google releases everything in "beta" and does not really test their own software like you would think. They let us create questions on StackOverflow and send in crash reports in order to test their products out. However, all the Android tools are *FREE* and most are open source vs Apple's closed source and yearly subscription.

Comment: @JPM I totally agree the error messages are not helpful. Can you post a question and I might be able to help? Or did this answer help you?

Comment: This is the right idea but the formatting of the repositories declaration is no longer valid. 'repositories' now needs to be a root element of build.gradle instead of appearing inside of buildscript{}. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20574180/10505

Comment: @greg7gkb Your statement is only half correct. The `buildscript` lists the repositories for the project usually for plugins. You can specify `repositories`  separately for dependencies.

Comment: Some information on Gradle Plugin and Gradle compatibiltiy [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

Comment: what should I change on my android studio? to make it work?

Comment: Android development has many stupid things. Why we should be bothered with all this gradle versions thing

Comment: When I try to do "./gradlew wrapper --gradle-distribution-url..." as you posted, I get this familiar error in the terminal: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'OneTwoThree
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what `OneTwoThree > Plugin` is but I just tested this out again and it works. It is from gradle themselves: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v4.1.0.

Comment: I first had to locate `gradlew` buried deep in `android-studio`. Then I had to set its executable bit. That can't be right, but running the command succeeded!

Comment: I also had to do File > Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have this problem in my gitlab runner. when run gradle with cmd there is no problem, but when run gradle with powershell it's reporting the error in this question. do you have any idea?

Comment: Just got this error on current working project. I didn't think to that, but it turns out it was my new anti-virus and firewall i freshly installed...

Comment: for #FLUTTER projects: was enough to run `./gradlew wrapper` in the android directory

Answer (score 39):

This can happen if you miss adding the Top-level build file.

Just add **build.gradle** to top level.

### It should look like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.xx.y'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

---

Comment: That is exactly what he has.

Comment: What about the existing contents of the file? Just delete them?

Comment: If you're doing the firebase tutorial you need 

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` 

and 

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I download the project from GitHub and the Gradle file was missing. **So I just create a new project with success build**. Then copy-paste the Gradle missing file. And re-build the project is working for me.

[image]

Comment: this solved my problem after several hours of trying other methods

Comment: copy the file from where. I also have a missing gradle file, but in my case, its the one in the app directory

Answer (score 5):

Root-gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x-all.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

In the project level build.gradle file, I have replaced this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

with this one

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

After adding both of those lines, and syncing, everything became fine.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this not as a solution meant for many, but for ***some people who may commit a simple mistake like specifying the wrong url for importing projects from SVN***. It is intended for those guys :)

This happened to me when I imported the project from SVN -> automatic prompt by Studio to open the project -> It asked for Gradle location  -> D:\Software\Android\gradle-2.5 -> Then the error.

The same project in a different SVN branch works fine with the Gradle plugin and Gradle which I have configured in Studio. I tried changing Android Gradle plugin and Gradle to get it working on the erring branch without any success.

Finally, I figured out that it was my following mistake:
I tried importing a specific Application alone instead of importing the application along with dependent library projects.
The url which I used for import initially had the Application porject's name at the end. Once I removed it, and specified the parent directory which contained both application project and its dependent project, everything went smooth :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem after one hour struggling with this error message:

I accidentally renamed the root `build.gradle` to filename in `builde.gradle`, so Android Studio didn't recognize it anymore.

**Renaming** it to `build.gradle` resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

I still got the error

```
 Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
```

Problem: jcenter() did not have the required libs

Solution: add google() as repo

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your grade file where you can see this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And change `classpath` to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: No. `gradle-experimental` is "experimental". This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @JaredBurrows The error in OP's question can happen with gradle-experimental as well.  It is happening to me today.  However, VladimirKulyk should know that using gradle-experimental is only recommended for NDK builds.

Answer (score 1):

I was using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 and faced with the same problem after I changed versions of Picasso and Retrofit in `dependencies` in `build.gradle` file.  I tried use many solutions, but without result. 
Then I cloned my project from remote git (where I pushed it before changing versions of dependencies) and it worked! After that I just closed current project and imported old project from Gradle file to IntelliJ IDEA again and it worked too! So, I think it was strange bug in intersection of IDEA, Gradle and Android plugin. I hope this information can be useful for IDEA-users or anyone else.

Comment: Is there a technical answer you can give with a specific code example?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your two build.gradle and settings.gradle files are in the correct directories as stated in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Then open "as existing project" in Visual Studio

Gradle is very finicky about this.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me, I guess something wrong happens between **ButterKnife** and **3.0.0 alpha5**.

However, I found that when I annotated any one sentence, either BUtterKnife or 3.0.0 alpha5, it works normally.

So, you should just avoid the **duplication or conflict**.

Comment: When I annotated any one sentence , either **ButterKnife** or **3.0.0 alpha5** ,

it works  normally .

Comment: Please make a new question instead answering here with a question.

Comment: Remember that every **alpha** release is not ready for production. You mustn't use alpha version in your code.

Comment: Sorry...

I solved this question on my computer , but  I can't understand WHY ....

Comment: Maybe this unconventional  method will helps .   Annotated any one will helps in Android Studio 3.0.0 alpha5 .

Comment: That's good for you :). Previously, your answer seems as a question for me. I think you need to elaborate it more. I'm sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Oh. yes . U are right .  I just attempt to learn  kotlin 1.1.3   XD  XD

Comment: Ok . i will  recorrect it right now !      thank you for a good guy !     多谢了

Comment: Making a details explanation will be a good for other who stumbled with the same problem. Maybe someday the answer will help me because I haven't had a single experience with kotlin yet. And you're very welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: For me, this issue was solely caused by the fact that I wasn't running Android Studio as administrator. I had the shortcut on Windows configured to always run as administrator, but after reinstalling Android Studio, the shortcut was replaced, and so it ran without administrator rights. This caused a lot of opaque errors, including the one in this question.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened when I accidently renamed the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

on file `app/build.gradle` to some other name. So, I fixed it by changing it to what it was.

Answer (score 1):

[FOR FLUTTER] go to your build Gradle then check if you have three paths

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I somehow removed the android tools classpath and was getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me using ***Android Studio 1.3.2***, however, since I had just created the project, I deleted it and created it again.
It seems that it had not been properly created by Android Studio the first time, not even the project folders where as expected.

Comment: Android Studio version should match the plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a the module task with android plugin 1.2.3 in module directory , the problem appears. Try this:

```
../gradlew -b ../build.gradle  -c ../settings.gradle  :module:xxx
```

Comment: This command is very hacky and Gradle 1.2.3 is extremely old.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message after making the following change in my top-level `build.gradle` to update to the latest version of gradle:

```
//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' old
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' //new
```

I foolishly made the change while I was connected behind a hostile workplace proxy. The proxy caused the `.jar` files for the new version of gradle to become corrupt. This can be verified by inspecting the jars to see if they are an unusual size or whether they can be unzipped.

In order to fix the mistake, I connected to my network at home (which is not behind a proxy) and did a refresh dependencies from the Terminal:

```
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

This caused the newer version of gradle to be re-downloaded and the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling, mine was 'com.android.a**p**lication'

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen when you have both `settings.gradle` and `settings.gradle.kts` files are present in project root directory (possibly with the same module included). You should only have one of these files.

Comment: Correct. This happened to me when I imported my project directly with build.gradle, found duplicate Gradle and properties file

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem and i did following things to resolve it.
i referred to https://developer.android.com/studio/build
and copy / pasted these following lines before apply plugin lines

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
}
```

}

Comment: jcenter has been obsoleted now

Answer (score -1):

module  app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

model{


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion  "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "com.iamsafe"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23





        }
     buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled = false
                useProguard = true
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))


            }
        }



    }

}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.2'
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-8-0.8.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-osgi-4.2.1-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.2.jar')
}


project build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case of issues check below code

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**1.5.0**'
}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties` inside your project directory check below `disctributionUrl`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-all.zip
```

If these are not compatible with each other then you end up in this issue.

For `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.` you need a version at least 2.8 but if you switch to a higher version like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0` then you need to update your gradle to 2.9 and above this can be done by changing `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties to 2.9 or higher as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

If you work on Windows , you must start Android Studio name by Administrator.
It solved my problem

Answer (score -3):

Just make sure you put the http and https proxy correctly when you create the app