# SDK Location not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just imported my eclipse project in android studio. it keeps my saying that

```
Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I have seen some tutorials of editing local.properties files but it didnt work. here is my project.properties file:

```
sdk.dir=E:\\Mod Eclipse\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\\sdk
```

Actual directory of my folder is :

**E:\Mod Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk**

Comment: [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365254/6521116)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should also change it on Project Structure.

- Close the current project and you'll see pop up with dialog which will then proceed to Configure option.

  Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> SDKs on left column -> Android SDK Home Path -> give the exact path as you did on local.properties and select Valid Target.

There you go.

Comment: This is in my local.properties   sdk.dir=E\:\\Mod Eclipse\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\\sdk

Comment: and this one is the exact location E:\Mod Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk

Comment: it should be single slash not double so in your case not E\:\\Mod Eclipse\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\\sdk, correct: E:\Mod Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk

Answer (score 36):

A quick note about this if trying to run a Facebook sample and this error pops up, make sure you select the build.gradle file in the root of Facebook sdk, for all the samples when 'opening an existing project'. I got this error when I tried to open the gradle for just the Scrumptious sample from the 3.22 SDK

Comment: I was not opening a Facebook sample but in my case I was trying to open the folder containing the sample.  When I opened the gradle file itself the error went away.

Comment: Same with the [CoRedux sample](https://github.com/freeletics/CoRedux/tree/master/sample), I had to open the CoRedux project in Android Studio and run the sample project from there rather than opening the sample project directly in Android Studio.

Answer (score 25):

My problem was:

1. I cloned a project from github
2. I clicked open existing Android Studio project
3. I chose the path of the **inner sample app instead of the containing folder**.

So what you should do is:

1. close the project.
2. click open existing Android Studio project
3. **select the parent folder** instead of the sample app.

Answer (score 23):

If you are sure that you have assigned correct **SDK** path in project settings,
and you can see it in **local.properties** as well, but still getting this error then there are chances that you are missing something in you project.

I was getting the same error after looking in to my project I found **settings.gradle** was missing.
[image]
and then add following script to your apps **build.gradle** 
[image]
You will not face this error any more. It worked for me may be **gradle set up** was the blocking issue

Comment: I now have a new different problem, but thanks, this indeed got rid of the SDK location not found error.

Comment: it solved my porblem but has started another problem saying 'plugin with id' com.android.application not found. Do you have any idea

Comment: @AbdulWaheed google that issue I think it has some gradle version compatibility issue look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found

Comment: @DeltaCap I have solved buddy :) it was gradle file issue

Answer (score 20):

The simplest solution sometimes is just do the *File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart*.

If it does not help then go for the more complicated stuff, as suggested in other answers

Comment: Yes, you are right it worked for me at least.

Comment: it worked. it worked on itself the new sdk location. thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add a local.properties with to set the sdk.dir like `sdk.dir=/Users/roofe/Library/Android/sdk`.

But please **note below**, which is very important,

add the local.properties to the **uppermost** path of the project. Here the **uppermost** have some difference with **root path** of a project.

For example in the below project, I just use the ijkplayer-example, but this module also used other module with different cpu architecture.

If I only add local.properties to ijkplayer-example will not work. Here will get sdk  location issue for other module.

While I can add the local.properties to the ijkplayer directory, then when I try to open the ijkplayer-example project, there will auto create a local.properties for ijkplayer-example, and everything works well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**In my case, it was a fresh install with checkout from github.**

- Just close the checkout window.
- Create a new project (not from git, just a fresh one).
- exit the project.
- checkout whatever you like

Its just the fastest way that I found.

Comment: This is actually, very intuitive and stupid at the same time. Shame AS devs!

Comment: I don't know if I should say thanks or be offended :)

Comment: Same thing happened to me! thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Sync project with Gradle files, It will modify the project's local.properties file.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I add just `local.properties` file where my project is located. In `local.properties`:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\dglig\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

such kind of path is there which is our Sdk path.

So just create local.properties file manually and inside this just copy the Sdk file location.

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue, and none of the answers given previously helped me. What I did was check for new API updates (in my case, I updated to API level 23) and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, I just clicked on File and then Choose Project Structure or Ctrl-Alt-Shift+S. This'll clearly show you the Android SDK location and an input box where you can browse to the correct one if it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Probably local.properties file missing.

Copy a local.properties from an existing file and add it to your current project. That worked for me.

Comment: When answering old questions, make sure that your solution is either *novel* or *unique*

Answer (score 0):

I installed the SDK again (from here for example :

https://www.mediafire.com/file/azbsqg6dmg7z7np/Sdk+tools+for+android+studio.rar/file

& it created the directory & the packages, after installation.

Now I open android studio & everything is normal.

Comment: You shouldn't install SDK from 3rd party URLs, they can contain viruses or backdoors.

Answer (score 0):

Everything posted so far was helpful in an overall learning capacity. However, most of the time, fixing one problem created others. What ended up working for me was completely deleting the GitHub project .zip file and any unzipped files. Then I made sure the correct .zip file was re-downloaded and unzipped. When it came time to open it in Android studio, I noticed there were 2 folders with identical project file names, one being contained in the other. The first (or upper) one is actually the .zip file. Open the other one!

Answer (score 0):

So I am using Android Hedgehog, and I was apparently facing the same problem. None of the answers helped me . The thing which solved this for me was I went to build.gradle(module: app) and there were some old dependencies which needed an update (Android gives yellow underlines for them). So I did that and did a gradle sync and voila it created a local.properties file by itself. It seems that I was trying to compile old code on newer compiler versions and thats what caused an issue. Attaching necessary outputs.

[This is the dependencies, 2 of them I updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHgIv.png)

2 dependencies I updated and android studio by itself created a local.properties file having this
[I got the local.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9hdv.png)
[Local.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL1ID.png)