# SDK Location not found- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sdk

I get this error when I compile the project:
 **Error: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.**
[This is a screenshoot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO3fm.png)

How can I solve it? The SDK location are good. The problem is i don't what is the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Add a environment variable with name ANDROID_HOME and assign your sdk location  path to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK Location not found in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596284/sdk-location-not-found-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Keshav1234 how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows:

```
Go to My Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
```

There add a variable ANDROID_HOME as the variable name and add your sdk path as its value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for selecting it as answer. Please do upvote it. Thanks.