# Error: SDK location not found even though it is correct in local.properties

Tags: android

I have cloned an Android project:

```
$ git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/company/company-android-app.git
$ cd company-android-app
$ ls
app/               build.gradle       firebase/          gradle/            
gradle.properties  gradlew            gradlew.bat        settings.gradle
```

When I try to open the app folder with android studio to start working with the project, I get `Gradle 'app' project refresh failed` and `Error: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`. The thing is, the SDK location is already set in local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
```

This is the same location as in other android projects that I have worked with on this machine. So why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

**EDIT** Additional info: I've checked in the configurations that the path has been set properly:

[image]

I can't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596388/6016830

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on a Windows 10 machine, had delete .Android , .AndroidStudio and .gradle folder (entire android studio cache) and start fresh.
at the very beginning of android studio setup it asks for sdk location i provide it there and it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

When I first opened the project in Android studio, I opened the `/app` directory. When I closed the project and opened the enclosing folder instead, it worked.