# Where to install the gradle wrapper plugin with android studio

Tags: android-studio, plugins, gradle, wrapper

Android Studio tells me that the current gradle wrapper 2.8 is outdated and I should update to 2.10.

Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\data\AndroidStudioProjects[projectname]\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

I changed the url in gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip but that didn't do anything.

I followed this answer to get gradle version 2.10: 
[Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

But how of where do I install this plugin in Android Studio so it knows where to find it?

Comment: You need to change your android studio setting to use the wrapper

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Project-level settings

and set: Use default gradle wrapper

This tells Android studio to use the wrapper version from the file that you just updated.

Comment: @PaulNaveda Please use the check mark to mark the answer as useful. And upvote it as well