# Android NDK onAndroid Studio 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Can I use the NDK with the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5' gradle plugin? Is it included or I should use the experimental plugin? And if so does the experimental support Instant Run and SVG images?

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I use the NDK with the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5' gradle plugin?

In your `local.properties`, specify your `ndk.dir` right next to your `sdk.dir`:

```
sdk.dir=/../android-sdk
ndk.dir=/../android-ndk
```

2. Is it included or I should use the experimental plugin?
   I would stay away from the latest plugins. Always use the latest release plugins. See here: [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found/25232725#25232725)

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

3. And if so does the experimental support Instant Run and SVG images?

The latest `2.0.0` release supports both insta-run and svg images. For the SVG images, make sure you use `compile 'com.android.appcompat-v7:23.3.0'`