# Android Studio and Gradle sync error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error at the top of my log file when trying to sync gradle.

"- Unable to locate last SDK used by Android tools "

I also see in messages failed to resolve junit:junit:4.12

I have two sdk's installed in sdk manager.

I also created a system variable in environmnet variables called ANDROID_HOME with the path being to the sdk directory. (This was a suggestion I read off a forum post)
I don't know what else I should do and have been stuck on this for awhile so any help is appreciated.

The log file is so log I put it in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/NpCpGiZ3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: I already followed that solution with the 130, but it didn't work for me. Any help is appreciated