# About error in imported project syncing in android studio

Tags: android

after importing project it is showing this error

Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
the build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.movienight"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY', "My API Key"
   }
 }
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
   dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'}
apply plugin: 'application'
```

Comment: see this link it might be helpful-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found

Comment: already tried it ...not working