# Gradle dsl method not found: 'android()' and Error (9,0)

Tags: java, android

I get an error after I import my project from eclipse. Not a problem in my code but I'm having trouble with build.gradle. How can I fix it?

build.gradle code here:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
main.resources.srcDirs = ['src']
test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}ode here
```

Comment: If this is the `build.gradle` file for an Android application the first line should be `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: after i added 'com.android.application' it now says plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Comment: See if this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24795079/1435985) helps in that case. Might be an older version of Gradle or one of the other dependencies. Are you using the new version of Android Studio 2.0 that was just released?

Comment: It's working now thanks George