# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found, what wrong?

Tags: android

I got the following error, can you all look at my code, how can I solve it?

I already download the file and restart a few times....

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.orbotix.ovalfreefall"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

my other gradle file

I dk is it this the file or not, I am really confused
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.orbotix.orbbasicloader"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    releaseCompile project(path: ':RobotCommonLibrary', configuration: 'release')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':RobotLeConnectorLibrary', configuration: 'release')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':RobotLibraryUmbrella', configuration: 'release')

    debugCompile project(path: ':RobotLeConnectorLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
    debugCompile project(path: ':RobotCommonLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
    debugCompile project(path: ':RobotLibraryUmbrella', configuration: 'debug')
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your other gradle file for the project?

Comment: what is the other gradle file call?

Comment: They are both called build.gradle but one says (Project) instead of (module). You posted the one that says module, I would like to see the project one.

Comment: try this answer on Stackover flow.......http://stackoverflow.com/a/25232725/3678308

Comment: I click on the two gradle seem to return me the same file

Comment: Then replace the contents of the Project one with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]

Go [here](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK) & hit download zip, then unzip it, then create a new Android project. In your file explorer, you will go to `Sphero-Android-SDK-master/libs/RobotLibrary.jar` and you will copy this file to the new `projectname/app/libs/` directory of the new android project. Then ensure the build.gradle(module:app) has this at the bottom. Then you can use the SDK.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IjVFG.png

Comment: The extra file you refer to is the old gradle file right?

Comment: I not quite sure which one you refer to, I do not have a app folder http://i.stack.imgur.com/8519T.png, I have change the current gradle file, but still have error

Comment: I am using window,  I open my file explorer, there are only 1 gradle file [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZJ2.png, simply put, I should move the build.gradle file into my src folder, and create a new build.gradle in the root folder. Right?

Comment: There is no app folder in window

Comment: You can take a look at here, some sample file I can make it work, some I couldn't https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK

Comment: Guess I have to move on, thanks for ur help

Comment: Just to test this SDK out

Comment: Nope just follow the exact instructions.

Comment: I don't get it, if I create a new project, how am I going to run the old SDK?

Comment: @Ryan, their SDK is nothing more than a Java library, as long as you have that library in your project, you'll be able to use it.

Comment: What i did now is import the project from the Sphero-Android-SDK-master project folder, they prompt me to do use don't know what gradle wrapper, I just click Okay, and I ghet the gradle-wrapper.properties....I not sure what that mean. right now I only have one build.gradle (Project: OrbBasicLoader)...fine I will upload the github file you later, what I get is just error after error

Comment: @Ryan, okay do you want to use their project samples or do you want to do a project  from scratch?

Comment: I want to get the app working from the existing code https://github.com/zero88/stackfolder, just try and compile this folder, I alrdy add dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
} This line to the gradle, it is not working....the lib is there, I don't know what is happening, just do whatever you want

Comment: @Ryan, I got it to work. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hprigilsx4uixn/TestRobotApp.zip?dl=0) is the project zipped. Just open it from AndroidStudio & deploy. Let me know when you download it so I can delete it.

Comment: alright, it work, manage to run without error, you can delete the file. However, whenever I connect to my Sphero via bluetooth, it seem to crash

Comment: did you create a new project? or did you just edit the file from my file?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't have a Sphero to try it with and help, but what you can do is keep this project and swap out the classes and activities from the sample folders. You may have to update the manifest, values or strings sometimes but the Gradle scripts are set. So don't lose this project!

Comment: I had to create a new project and then I imported the necessary classes, activities, values.xml and strings.xml, etc

Comment: Thanks I will work on it

Comment: I try to recreate a new project, but import com.orbotix.ConvenienceRobot;, my orbotix become red in colour, I am not able to import anything related to orbotix, what could be the problem?

Comment: @Ryan, you have to add the RobotLibrary every time you make a new project. I actually had inconsistent results with the process in my answer but more consistent results with another one, so I'll update my answer one more time either today or tomorrow. I'll comment here when I do that.

Comment: I try your method on the buttondrive sample, however, my app seem to crash whenever I connected to the sphero, it work well when I off my bluetooth, it is kinda weird