# Error:(1, 0) plugin: 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I got this error when I was creating new project. I tried to resolve but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24795079/4791726

Comment: @AlbAtNf This thing I tried didn't worked.

Comment: I don't know how you got an upvote for this - please always let us know _what_ you have tried, in detail.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**First:**
Add the following code to the top of your build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
} 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Second:** Find the gradle-wrapper.properties.
Change the last sentence to this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I am checking wait.

Comment: This is working. Thanks..

Comment: ok..i will accept it.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!