# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

This is, unfortunately, not a duplicate of [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found) - solutions from there don't help me.

The problem occurred today after updating Android Studio when it said I should update Gradle to 2.14. I clicked "OK" and now my project is somehow broken. The error I get is in the title.

This is my root `build.gradle`:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
           jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()


 }
}
```

And this is the first line in the project `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
```

If I change it to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I get an error

```
Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
```

Comment: Post both your project and module `build.gradle` files

Comment: @Shaishav: The project-level one is already posted in my question in its entirety. Here's the module build file: https://gist.github.com/VioletGiraffe/826ba80b7e7d800c20aa067fa9506c11

Comment: Not aware of the requirements in the latest gradle version but, the docs say use `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4"` in project build.gradle file

Comment: @Shaishav: that almost looked as if it was going to work, but... "Error:Could not find com.android.tools.b‌​uild:gradle-experimen‌​tal:0.7.0-alpha4."

Comment: I took it from here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental ... it synced properly in mine.

Comment: @Shaishav: note that they also list `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`. Problems started when Android Studio updated it to 2.14 today.
So basically, no one knows which version name to put in the `classpath` now?

Comment: oh...sorry...totally new plugin for me :/

Comment: @Shaishav: There's also this, but I don't know what to make of it either: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an NDK project which means I couldn't use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'`. I needed `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3"`. Updating from 0.7.0 to 0.7.3 solved all my problems that were caused by updating Gradle to 2.14.