# Android initial start-up

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, mobile-application, android-sdk-tools

I have just installed Android and all relative tools required to run android development. Unfortunately at the initial build of Gradle sync, event log prints out an error message

**Error message (Event log):**

Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.applications' not found. Consult IDE Log for more details

Here's is the current Project (build.gradle) My application configuration:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to
//   all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the current Module (build.gradle) configuration:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
 }

 dependencies {
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: i read the whole solution it didn't work right @W4R10CK

Comment: It generally happens when u dont have `gradle` liberary, try adding it along with googleplay liberary.

Comment: add this to dependencies on your below file. `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
    `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

Comment: Well yeah i tried nitinsingh attempt to remove the gradle dir and let android recreate appropriate gradle and i found that same dependency you mentioned it appeared into a new module with extra additonal dependency such as compile and testCompile @W4R10CK

Comment: yep, the dependencies you see are by default, I must say now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
```

Shutdown Android Studio
Rename/remove `.gradle` folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
Gradle build success !

Rebuild project.... success !

Out of curiousity I compared the structure of the old `.gradle` and the new one.

they were pretty different.!

Comment: Lol... Ok some how it worked :/ Can you clarify out of your curiosity such kind of act ? @nitinsingh

Answer (score 0):

1. make a file named "settings.gradle".
2. add this line to this file ->
   include ':app'
3. copy this file to the root directory of your project.
4. Re-open project

Comment: Sorry such kind of file did exist at initial configuration apart from dependencies that were required where missing on Module file @HiteshLalwani

Comment: in that case, i think u will have to update "gradle-wrapper.properties" distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip