# gradle project sync failed even after upgrading gradle plugin

Tags: java, android

Gradle project sync failed and did not get answers from other related questions.  Here are the details of my situation.

Initial sync attempt yielded the following error message:

```
Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

I have Android Studio 3.0.  The build.gradle file includes the following dependency:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'

  The gradle-wrapper.properties file includes the following distribution URL:

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle I need to make some changes.
**First**, update the Gradle version for Android Studio 3.0 in gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=\
  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
(I believe the backslash right after the equal sign is an error and did not make that change.)

**Second**, add the following buildscript repository to build.gradle:

google()

**Third**, change the build.gradle dependency:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

The second and third changes apply the latest version of the Android plug-in.

When I try to sync after these changes it fails again with the following new error:

Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found.

The error refers to the first line of build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

What is happening and why?  I recently added NDK to Android Studio.  The project I'm trying to sync includes C code.  I'm not completely certain I added NDK correctly.  I wonder if that could be part of the problem.

Comment: does creating a new project syncs successfully?

Comment: Yes, it appears to sync correctly, but a regular project did not set up for C code.  So I tried it with "C++ support enabled".  That also appeared to sync correctly.  I'm concerned again that it's an issue with my NDK setup.  How do I start a new project with C instead of C++ support?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `gradle-wrapper.properties` is incorrect. You must include `\` in it. It should be something like this:

```
#Sat Jun 17 17:47:18 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Then, add the experimental classpath to project build.gradle. Something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Check the [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) for details.

Comment: Thanks.  According to a link in the guide I think an appropriate gradle plug-in version is 0.11.0-alpha-preview-02.  I changed the build.gradle line to this.  Sync yielded an error indicating this plug-in requires gradle 4.0, not 4.1.  I changed the gradle-wrapper properties line to 4.0.

  Sync then seemed to proceed much further, but I get yet another error.

Cannot set readonly property: proguardFiles for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType

  What is this error indicating?

Answer (score 2):

**Go to your build.gradle version or update it**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change you `dependencies` `classpath`

**All steps are here :**

- Open build.gradle and change the gradle version to the recommended version:
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'` to
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`
- Hit `'Try Again'`
- In the messages box it'll say `'Fix Gradle Wrapper and re-import project'` Click that, since the minimum gradle version is `3.3`
- A new error will popup and say `The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0` - Hit `Update Build Tools version and sync project`
- A window may popup that says `Android Gradle Plugin Update recommended`, just update from there.

Now the project should be runnable now on any of your android virtual devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Gradle version is compatible with your Android Gradle Plugin.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle