# Android Studio: Gradle project sync failed after update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been messing around with Android Studio after a long time without doing it. I tried to use Git (and after deleted the .git directory) and I also performed an Android Studio update some I am not sure where things went wrong.

I ended-up re-importing the project and now I get the following error:

- app:sync failed -> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

[android studio error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7UJo.png)

Comment: Refer to this answer:
[Answer by Jared Burrows: StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232725/7535695)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. In the end I decided to create a new empty project as to get a new clean gradle and structure and paste the rest of files in-there. It has worked so the problem is solved. Not sure yet what I had messed...

Thank you all.

Comment: I always do this for obsolete projects, and it always works; it takes shorter time WRT syncing that yields a failure at the end of the day