# How to load project into Android Studio (which files to insert and which to not)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to *move a project* from one computer to another. Here's how I did it:

1. From the **android project** folder, I copied the **entire folder** from the selected application
2. Put it on g. drive
3. Opened the **entire folder** in the Android Studio of another computer

It's all messed up, the structure of the application is wrong, there are plenty of folders...

When I open only the s**rc folder** and the **build.gradle** file, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

> MyApp Folder (These are all the files that are in the project folder):

[image]

> What does it look like when I load it:

[image]

If you can tell me exactly which files and folders to load, I **unfortunately can't access the first computer** now so all I have is that folder on the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delete the build folder in your project then clean the project and then rebuild it.Make sure your Android studio is equal or higher version then your old computer.If it doesn't work then refer the below link

[Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: What should I choose from the first picture?

Comment: Yes ... In first image delete build folder you can find this in app -> build location , then rebuild the project in Android studio now the build folder will be create again.

Answer (score 3):

Close project from the android studio and removing .idea folder and *.iml files, and Then opening project and build.