# Android synchronization failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

I am new to android developing. I am trying to open an existing project and get it to compile. this the first time for me using android studio and the Gradle file got me a little confused.
I am trying to synchronize it but it is failing. This is the content of Gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "de.establishement.packagelist"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationTrial "android.support.test.trial.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                debuggable= true
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

I downloaded this project and I have it in my Desktop. this is what I get in my build messages:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/mac/Desktop/javaproject/build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/mac/Desktop/javaproject/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/mac/Desktop/javaproject/build.gradle': 21: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
  In case you tried to configure a property named 'debuggable', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
   @ line 21, column 25.
                 debuggable: true
                             ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
ERROR: startup failed:
build file '/Users/mac/Desktop/javaproject/build.gradle': 21: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'debuggable', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
 @ line 21, column 25.
               debuggable: true
                           ^

1 error

Open File
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: make sure you have  build.gradle(Project) and you have last update Gradle version and last version of android studio

Comment: another note compile is deprecated and must replaced with implementation

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja I have 5.4.1 version of Gradle and I will try to update it.

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja when I open a new empty project the Gradle seems to be fine and it builds successfully. when I open the existing project, however, It doesn't. shall I copy the content of the Gradle files that works to the other files or would that mess up the project

Comment: so it is work now ?! don't copy all content just copy the dependencies from fine file to another

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja I updated all the sdk tools, launched android studio again with new project it is fine, with that specific project it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logs you must change `debuggable: true` to `debuggable = true`

Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use. Try this;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "de.establishement.packagelist"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationTrial "android.support.test.trial.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                debuggable true //This row is wrong.
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and this is what I get when trying to synchronize: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'javatest'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Ok. Change this section. debuggable= true => debuggable true  @waffles123

Comment: in my original Gradle or in the one you provided. Because yours already has that!