# Gradle issue with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm just starting to learn Android Development and after installing Android Studio I get this error every time i create a project

> org.gradle.api.plugins.unknownpluginexception

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Comment: unfortunately no