# Error while updating gradling with lower version and v7

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, barcode-scanner

Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'
compile files('libs/scanning.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have your top level build.gradle file(project-level) and confirm that the following is defined.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
}
```

Project level is found in:

**Project-name/build.gradle**

While app level is found in:

**Project-name/app/build.gradle**

Once this is set, run the following command on android studio terminal and watch keenly on what could be still be raising any further issues on the output.

```
 ./gradlew build -i
```

Refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)