# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. How i can solve this?

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Caique\Desktop\Projects\adeus_fraudas\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

How i can solve this?

[image: App Path]
[image: Master path]

Comment: In applicationId i write an id example, but i already had the firebase id application inside there before.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error too when I tried to add firebase manually I fixed it by removing  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and also `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx' implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')`from my build.gradle file which I  added earlier from the flutter docs and then added the plugin by using `flutter pub add firebase`