# Add Android plugin to gradle init script

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently working on creating my own Gradle custom distribution and I want to add some default settings to all my Android projects. I tried to do this with the following init script:

```
initscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      google()
    }
    
    dependencies {
      classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

gradle.allprojects {
    android {
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

but with this I get `Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.` What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to move `apply plugin: `com.android.application` inside the `allprojects` block. You might also need to add put your configuration blocks (android and dependencies) into a `afterEvaluate { }` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For gradle init script, you must use the fully qualified class name of the plugin instead of the id. So you will have to apply the plugin this way:

```
apply plugin: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when following this: Plugin with id 'com.android.internal.version-check' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **Gradle version is compatible with your Android Gradle Plugin.**

For more information you can follow the link below, if it helps you
[plugin with id com.android.application not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

Change the `initscript` to `buildscript`.

---

And also, does this `build.gradle` in root project/directy? Because you Android Gradle Plugin is applied in the gradle module not in the root.

So apply:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
```

inside your module's `build.gradle`.