# Unable to apply plugin in gradle init script

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Here is my gradle init script.

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin="java")
    apply(plugin="application")
    apply(plugin="org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin")
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

However, I am getting `Plugin with id 'org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin' not found.` error.

I have tried the solutions from the following questions but none of them solves the problem.

[Add Android plugin to gradle init script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262078/add-android-plugin-to-gradle-init-script)

Comment: The plugin ID of the Spring Boot plugin is [`org.springframework.boot`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot), not `org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin`.

Comment: `initscript` should be `buildscript`.

Comment: @aSemy I have tried that initially and it does not work.

Comment: @MartinZeitler this is init script that is found in `init.d`. buildscript does not work here.

Comment: Have you considered editing the wrong file?

Comment: @aSemy in a [`gradle.init`/ `init.gradle.kts` script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) the way you reference the plugin you want to apply is referenced by its class. So `org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin` is correct and `"org.springframework.boot"` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my solution after googling around.

In order to apply plugins in gradle init script that is written in kotlin DSL,
one has to use the following

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin="java")
    apply(plugin="application")
    apply<org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin>()
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

In order to apply third party plugins in the init script, one has to use the form `apply<path.to.classname>()`