# An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is my first flutter app and I'm facing this problem. I have tried many solutions but didn't work!please need help.
build.gradle:
'`dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings:7.4.0-alpha10' classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"}`'

build.radle:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuREP.png

Answer (score 0):

Check new answer in the [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232725/19976446)

Comment: Thanks Sugan so I try it but still have this probleme !!
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\thinkpad\AndroidStudioProjects\test5\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Share the build gradle file where error occurred.

Comment: * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\thinkpad\AndroidStudioProjects\test5\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
line 25it's --->' apply plugin: 'com.android.application' ' and i putted my build.gradle file up in my quest.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: I tried to update the version of my android studio to the last one from your suggestion, now it's fixed ,thanks a lot .