# AChartEngine And Android Studio

Tags: android, charts, android-studio, achartengine

I have to create an application that makes extensive use of charts. 
Reading the web I chose achartengine that seems to have everything I need.

I downloaded the jar file, I plugged in the libs folder, I selected "add to library" and I lunch the gradlew clean. 
Result in the sources where I do the import of org.achartengine.xxxx I always returned the error that fails to resolve symbols .

Do you have suggestions? 
Thank you 
Andrea

Comment: Does it help if you click the Sync with Gradle Files button in the toolbar?

Answer (score 25):

I am able to use this library in my Android Studio project, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574111/add-maven-repository-to-build-gradle) explains how to add AChartEngine repo to your project.

What I did:

1. Added following to project-wide build.gradle (one from the project root):

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven {
               url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. For every module that uses the library, add this to its build.gradle (you may put this to the top-level build.gradle if it should be included in all modules):

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile group: 'org.achartengine', name: 'achartengine', version: '1.2.0'
   }
   ```

Now I can use the library in the project, I see the classes in code assist popups and build runs as succeeds.

Comment: The maven code works. Updated with **Gradle 2.5** new syntax : `maven{
            url = "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
        }`

Comment: hi i am getting this error : org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset can not be resolved

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the new version (1.2.0) is not available for download anymore in the http://www.achartengine.org/ site. and that's why the gradle/maven method doesn't work (or the snapshot file was removed).
I succeeded using and adding it to my project by downloading the jar file from here:
https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine/files/460139/achartengine-1.2.0.zip