# Could not find which method maven() to invoke from this list:

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently attempting to emulate (and then build) and Ionic App (w/ Angular) for Android. I feel the need to preface this by saying am *not* an Android developer, this is the first time I've had to set up the environment so I apologize for any "obvious" mistakes or missed steps.

I have been unable to get past this error (appears after running `ionic cordova emulate android --debug --consolelogs`):

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.794 secs
[11:12:25]  lint finished in 1.74 s 
Error: /path/to/app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/path/to/app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find which method maven() to invoke from this list:
public abstract org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler#maven(groovy.lang.Closure)
public abstract org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler#maven(org.gradle.api.Action)
```

**I get a similar message within Android Studio when I attempt to Build my project or sync Gradle:**

```
Could not find which method maven() to invoke from this list:
public abstract org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler#maven(groovy.lang.Closure)
public abstract org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler#maven(org.gradle.api.Action)
Open File
```

**The line in my `build.gradle` file that's failing looks like this:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven ()        < HERE
        jcenter()
        google ()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.7'
    }
}
```

**For context, I have:**

Downloaded Android Studio, JDK, and the SDK Tools as well as (in trying to troubleshoot) installed Gradle and Maven via homebrew.

Added the following paths to my `.bash_profile` (and confirmed that the file paths contain what they say they do, with matching versions):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.7/bin
```

Accepted all license terms via the CLI sdkmanager

Created a Virtual Device via the AVD Manager

Running `ionic info` returns the following:

```
cli packages: (/Users/katesowles/.node/lib/node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.1
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
    Node              : v8.7.0
    npm               : 5.4.2 
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145 
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/katesowles/Library/Android/sdk
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Running `mvn --version` returns

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T11:49:05-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Running `gradle --version` returns

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation 25.171-b11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64
```

Any help in finding a way past this and to a completed, successful build would be SO greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

You should add this:

```
  repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
        } //  some dependency like this.
    }
```

If you have a maven with authentication you can use:

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
               credentials {
                   username xxx
                   password xxx
               }
               url    'http://mymaven/xxxx/repositories/releases/'
            }
}
```

It is important order.

**Note :** You will need to define the repository outside of buildscript. The buildscript configuration block only sets up the repositories and dependencies for the classpath of your build script but not your application. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574180/6891563)

Comment: Where outside of `buildscript` should I put this? Still in my `build.gradle` file? I really have no idea about any of this so I'm sorry for what I'm sure are basic questions. Additionally, where would I find a dependency for maven like the URL you've shown (or is that the exact one to include)?

Comment: First tell me where you got need to add maven(). that will tell you its url

Comment: I didn't add it manually, it was generated when I built my app via Ionic+Cordova build script.

Comment: I edited answer, you will put `repositories ` after `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: Okay just go to app level build.gradle. and follow the answer instruction.

Comment: Thank you for the specificity. I've added `repositories` below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application` as you've shown, and attempted run the Ionic+Cordova build process again, but I'm met with the same error message as before, no change.

Comment: consider removing `maven()` from repository.